# Java - название класса

Tags: java, ооп, классы

Подскажите пожалуйста, как сравнить название класса с заданной строкой( строка введена пользователем).
Можно ли как-то записать название класса в строковую переменную?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Ну конечно можно.

```
String name = MyClass.class.getName();
```

или

```
String name = MyClass.class.getSimpleName();
```

Тогда будет короткое имя класса, без имени пакета.
Или так:

```
MyClass my = new MyClass();
String name = my.getClass().getName();
```